# get img path when on different location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the API the image url value is `img/something.jpg`.

When I consume on the homepage it's ok.

I can use:

```
$scope.img = response.data.imgUrl
```

When I'm creating another page I do the same the image is broken.

I tried in the view

```
<img src='../{{img}}'>
```

it doesn't work.

How can I deal with this situation?

Comment: User relative paths instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the "other page" is in another directory (or virtual one).

If you append a `/` at the front of the URL, I expect it will work.

This is because the URL is relative to the current page. To demonstrate, the web browser is requesting `http://yoursite.com/another/page/img/something.jpg` for your image, instead of `http://yoursite.com/img/something.jpg`.

Comment: like how? like this? `$scope.img = '/' + response.data.imgUrl` ?

Comment: @NisaK yep, exactly